# brower.acceptAlert is not a function in webdriverIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I'm using webdriver.io to write a suite of test cases.

npm-v 6.4.1,
node-v 10.11.0,
wdio-mocha-framework:^0.6.4,
wdio-phantomjs-service: ^0.2.2,
wdio-selenium-standalone-service: 0.0.12,
webdriver: ^5.18.6,
webdriverio": ^4.14.1

[image: Alert that i need to accept]

I need to accept an alert box in chrome browser but with a browser.acceptAlert(); it's not working and showing this error.

[image: The error I am getting while using this code]

Comment: You should try `alertAccept`.

Comment: That's not an available function in webdriverIO

Comment: What is the version of wdio? If not please install `npm i wdio`.

Comment: v4 have function `alertAccept` && v5 have `acceptAlert`.

Answer (score 0):

Fuction `browser.acceptAlert()` work only in [webdriverIO v5](https://webdriver.io/docs/api/webdriver.html#acceptalert).

You use webdriverIO v4 so try do `browser.alertAccept()` more in wdio v4 [documentation](http://v4.webdriver.io/v4.12/api/protocol/alertAccept.html).